# Working with php explode?

Tags: php, explode

I've got  a list of countries, sometimes the list contains just one country and sometimes more. This is my code:

```
<?php if($this->value): ?>
<a class="tag" href="{{env::url}}/business?land=<?php echo $this->value; ?>" title="<?php echo $this->value; ?>"><?php echo $this->value; ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The output right now is: "Germany,Austria,Switzerland".

I want to create a link for every country, how can I do that?

I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Are you looking for a loop?

Comment: I dont know^^ my php is not so good.

Comment: you need to use foreach loop to loop through countries

Comment: I think your code is not complete. So post the whole code... code and output are not sync.

Comment: Thats the code for the country attribute, that is given from my CMS.

Comment: Where does German,Australia,Switzerland come from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are getting comma separate list of countries inside $this->value.

We can use function like explode to split that string into array and then use foreach to loop through array and generate individual link

```
<?php if($this->value): ?>
    <?php
        $array = explode( ',', $this->value );
    ?>
    <?php foreach($array as $value): ?>
        <a class="tag" href="{{env::url}}/business?land=<?php echo $value; ?>" title="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></a> - 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `$this->value` is an array so you can get the countries one by one using `foreach` loop like below:

```
<?php if($this->value): ?>
    <? $countries = $this->value; ?>
    <? foreach ($countries as $country): ?>
        <a class="tag" href="{{env::url}}/business?land=<?php echo $country; ?>" title="<?php echo $country; ?>"><?php echo $country; ?></a>
    <? endforeach; ?>
<? endif; ?>
```

if it is string than you can use explode() function and get the countries as an array like:

```
<?php $countries = explode("," , $this->value); ?>
```

and pass this `$countries` array to foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

For achieving this you need to check and explode the country string by comma and than loop it in foreach.

**Sample code:**

```
<?php
if ($this->value) {
    $countries = explode(",", $this->value);
    if (count(countries) > 1) {
        foreach ($countries as $country) {
            ?>
            <a class="tag" href="{{env::url}}/business?land=<?php echo $country; ?>" title="<?php echo $country; ?>"><?php echo $country; ?></a>
            <?php
        }
    } else {
        ?>
        <a class="tag" href="{{env::url}}/business?land=<?php echo $this->value; ?>" title="<?php echo $this->value; ?>"><?php echo $this->value; ?></a>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```